# CiviEvent automatically send survey after event

Tags: civievent

How can we automatically send a survey form to participants after an event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) extension to do that? There is a [CiviRules Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/) which should help you to understand what it does and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by 'survey form' but you can set a Scheduled Reminder to go out x hours, or y days, after an event.

Then that link can go to eg a Profile or if you are using Drupal, a webform so that the 'survey' gets recorded as an Activity AND you can mark off on the Participant record that they have responded.